# nested static class method cannot be accessed by outer class?

Tags: java, nested-class

I created a nested static class like this:

```
public class OuterClass {

  public static class NestedClass {
    public static String getName() {
      //Some stuff
      return "Name";
    }
  }

  //Now am not able to call the method *getName()* inside *OuterClass*
  NestedClass.getName(); //Compile complains here
}
```

But I can do it from another class

```
public class TestOuterClass {
  public void testName() {
    OuterClass.NestedClass.getName();
  }
}
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work withen the class its been defined.

Comment: That doesn't compile because you can't have statements outside a method body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place `NestedClass.getName();` inside a method such as `main`.

This compiles and runs properly:

```
public class OuterClass {

  public static class NestedClass {
    public static String getName() {
      //Some stuff
      return "Name";
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
      System.out.println(NestedClass.getName());
  }
}
```

Output:

```
$ javac OuterClass.java
$ java OuterClass
Name
$
```